# CSS text on overlay

Tags: html, css

So I have this code which plays a video on my website.

When I run it locally the video is fine and the text is over it

When I upload it the code is below it?

I used z-index 2? to bring the text to the front

On the website it looks like this 
https://gyazo.com/b44cff259296ad76b3542880203bed14
Locally it looks like this - https://gyazo.com/448e05e2e55cc904860cc2c62f0f33cc

So I'm very new to stack overflow and cannot get my head around the CTRL + K
So here are 2 ghostbin links. (Sorry)
HTML Code - https://ghostbin.com/paste/87ctg
CSS Code - https://ghostbin.com/paste/cwnsf

```css
body {
  background-color: #000000;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: "Futura Hv BT";
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.v-header {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
}

.container {
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.fullscreen-video-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fullscreen-video-wrap video {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.header-content {
  z-index: 2;
```

```html
<header class="v-header container">
  <div class="fullscreen-video-wrap">
    <video src="https://gazzy.xyz/video.mp4" autoplay="true" loop="true">

            </video>
  </div>

  <div class="header-content">
    <h1>gazzy</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/fovon/">steam</a>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://discord.gg/Gb5nrNN">discord server</a>
    <button type="button" onclick="copyToClipboard('gazzy#1004'); alert('discord username copied to clipboard')">discord</button>
  </div>


</header>
```

Comment: My guess is that your local version is running a slightly different version of the code than the one you have on the live website. Maybe you have some per-processor that tidy the code when you pack it for deployment?

Comment: Hello Gazzy. Welcome to SO. Please put the code into the post.

Comment: please include any js that you are using

Comment: Your code seems fine. Try hard refreshing your browser by SHIFT + F5. It's probably getting an old cached version of the CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

Im also new to web dev, however i figured that if you try margins around the text div it might work? Maybe try:
`mergin-top:20px;`
and see how that edits the text, if not try going through the steps here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_text.asp
or try this video if you hate reading like me:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=edCuCED3Zmo